# OAuth and Facebook page tabs

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm in need of more of an explanation than an answer, per se - I'm building a page tab, which will pull certain images from a particular album belonging to the page. This does not require an access token, so there is no need to ask for permissions from visitors.

I can add like/share options which also work fine without an access token or authorisation.

How do I get basic user info (id, name etc) without requesting authorisation? It's a page tab, on Facebook, so therefore the visitor must be logged in already.

Just seems counter intuitive if I have to request permissions to perform what is essentially pretty standard actions.

I'm using the javascript SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's a page tab, on Facebook, so therefore the visitor must be logged in already.

The user may be logged in to Facebook – but he is not necessarily *connected* to your app (yet). And you *need* him to be, to get his user id.

Make a call to `FB.login` without asking for any permissions in the `scope` parameter – that’ll prompt the user to connect to your app, giving it only “basic” permissions to read his personal data. That’ll give you his user id in the `response.authResponse` (and also will lead to his user id being included in the `signed_request` next time he visits your page tab).

After that, you can get his basic user info be calling `/me` via the Graph API.

Comment: thought that was the case. Was hoping there might be a way around it, as the app is simply an interface to like photos, which can obviously be done just by visiting the page/albums anyway. Not to worry, just means an extra click for visitors. Using FB.login doesn't return an access token though does it?

Comment: Yes, it does. Log the response to console in your callback function, you’ll see what data it contains.